# Spring microservices and kubernetes error

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm using eureka-client, eureka-server, spring-cloud-starter-gateway and kafka to build my api. Using microservices, it works like this: the command sends a request to kafka for it to run, the Kafka that is installed on my machine and is not in a container. Command example:

```
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, ContactAdmSaveDto> kafkaTemplate;

@Override
public String create(ContactAdmSaveDto data) {
    kafkaTemplate.send("contact-adm-insert", data);
    return "Cadastrado com sucesso!";
}
```

application.properties command producer:

```
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=springboot:9092
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer


server.port = 30006
spring.application.name = contact-adm-command
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://springboot:30002/eureka
eureka.instance.hostname=springboot
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
```

Example from Kafka:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = {"contact-adm-insert"}, groupId = "contact-adm")
public void consume(String record){

    try {
        
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ContactAdm data = mapper.readValue(record, ContactAdm.class);
        
        ContactAdm cat = new ContactAdm();
        cat.setCell_phone(data.getCell_phone());
        cat.setEmail(data.getEmail());
        cat.setTelephone(data.getTelephone());
       
        ContactAdm c = contactAdmRepository.save(cat);

        ContactAdmMongo catm = new ContactAdmMongo();
        catm.setCell_phone(data.getCell_phone());
        catm.setEmail(data.getEmail());
        catm.setTelephone(data.getTelephone());
        catm.setContact_id(c.getContact_id());

        contactAdmRepositoryMongo.save(catm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info(e.toString());
    }

}
```

application.properties kafka consumer:

```
server.port = 30005
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=springboot:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=contact-adm
```

`springboot` is a host name for my machine's ip

follow my gateway. Remembering that all kafka services are not registered in the gateway they are only to run when they are called by the command:

```
server.port=30000
spring.application.name=routing
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://springboot:30002/eureka/
eureka.instance.hostname=springboot
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true


#spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true

#spring.main.web-application-type=reactive
spring.cloud.gateway.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=user
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://USER
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates=Path=/user/**

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=testes
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://TESTES
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates=Path=/testes/**

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].id=user-command
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].uri=lb://USER-COMMAND
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates=Path=/user-command/**

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].id=category-product-command
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].uri=lb://CATEGORY-PRODUCT-COMMAND
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].predicates=Path=/category-product-command/**

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].id=category-product-query
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].uri=lb://CATEGORY-PRODUCT-QUERY
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].predicates=Path=/category-product-query/**

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].id=cart-purchase-command
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].uri=lb://CART-PURCHASE-COMMAND
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].predicates=Path=/cart-purchase-command/**

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[6].id=cart-purchase-query
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[6].uri=lb://CART-PURCHASE-QUERY
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[6].predicates=Path=/cart-purchase-query/**

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[7].id=contact-adm-command
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[7].uri=lb://CONTACT-ADM-COMMAND
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[7].predicates=Path=/contact-adm-command/**

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[8].id=contact-adm-query
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[8].uri=lb://CONTACT-ADM-QUERY
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[8].predicates=Path=/contact-adm-query/**
```

This all works fine but I want to put it on kubernetes so I created the services images with the following command: `mvn spring-boot:build-image` and with the DockerFile:

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
EXPOSE 30000
ADD src/main/resources/routing/public.pem src/main/resources/routing/public.pem
ADD /target/routes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar routes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","routes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Generating all services images and placing them in the docker hub to be pulled by docker kubernetes with the following deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cart-purchase-kafka
  labels:
    app: cart-purchase-kafka
spec:
  replicas: 1
  # strategy:
  #   rollingUpdate:
  #     maxUnavailable: 0
  #     maxSurge: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: cart-purchase-kafka
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: cart-purchase-kafka
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: cart-purchase-kafka
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:cart-purchase-kafka
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 30011
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred


---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cart-purchase-command
  labels:
    app: cart-purchase-command
spec:
  replicas: 1
  # strategy:
  #   rollingUpdate:
  #     maxUnavailable: 0
  #     maxSurge: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: cart-purchase-command
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: cart-purchase-command
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: cart-purchase-command
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:cart-purchase-command
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 30012
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cart-purchase-query
  labels:
    app: cart-purchase-query
spec:
  replicas: 1
  # strategy:
  #   rollingUpdate:
  #     maxUnavailable: 0
  #     maxSurge: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: cart-purchase-query
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: cart-purchase-query
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: cart-purchase-query
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:cart-purchase-query
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 30010
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred


---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user
  labels:
    app: user
spec:
  replicas: 1
  # strategy:
  #   rollingUpdate:
  #     maxUnavailable: 0
  #     maxSurge: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: user
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: user
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: user
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:user
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 30015
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred


---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user-command
  labels:
    app: user-command
spec:
  replicas: 1
  # strategy:
  #   rollingUpdate:
  #     maxUnavailable: 0
  #     maxSurge: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: user-command
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: user-command
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: user-command
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:user-command
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 30004
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user-command-insert
  labels:
    app: user-command-insert
spec:
  replicas: 1
  # strategy:
  #   rollingUpdate:
  #     maxUnavailable: 0
  #     maxSurge: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: user-command-insert
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: user-command-insert
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: user-command-insert
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:user-command-insert
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 30003
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
```

The big problem so far is that when I run it without Kubernetes it works fine but when I generate the pods it gives errors like:

```
NAME                                        READY   STATUS                   RESTARTS      AGE
category-product-command-565f758d5d-4wwnf   0/1     Evicted                  0             10m
category-product-command-565f758d5d-54pd5   0/1     Error                    0             29m
category-product-command-565f758d5d-hmb8k   0/1     Pending                  0             2m47s
category-product-command-565f758d5d-k6gmf   0/1     Evicted                  0             10m
category-product-command-565f758d5d-lkd25   0/1     Error                    0             41m
category-product-command-565f758d5d-ltbnl   0/1     Evicted                  0             10m
category-product-command-565f758d5d-m7wwx   0/1     ContainerStatusUnknown   1             35m
category-product-command-565f758d5d-p42td   0/1     Error                    0             54m
category-product-command-565f758d5d-pmfmh   0/1     Error                    0             10m
category-product-command-565f758d5d-qbthd   0/1     Evicted                  0             10m
category-product-command-565f758d5d-qf969   0/1     Evicted                  0             10m
category-product-command-565f758d5d-twjvq   0/1     Evicted                  0             10m
category-product-command-565f758d5d-vfrwq   0/1     ContainerStatusUnknown   1             22m
category-product-command-565f758d5d-xftpq   0/1     Error                    0             47m
category-product-command-565f758d5d-xsg47   0/1     Evicted                  0             10m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-262n8     0/1     Evicted                  0             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-2klh8     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-2mgp8     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-2rlmm     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-2z57p     0/1     Evicted                  0             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-424pj     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-4cnp2     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-4v586     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-5d7sg     0/1     Evicted                  0             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-5mndm     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-5rcgg     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-5rlz7     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-69w7h     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-6czbj     0/1     Evicted                  0             36m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-6rtvb     0/1     Evicted                  0             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-6t4km     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-7pkd7     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-99z2b     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-9lfqq     0/1     Error                    1 (42m ago)   53m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-9nrm4     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-bzx52     0/1     Evicted                  0             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-d62b5     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-dbhp4     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-dscdk     0/1     Evicted                  0             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-fnjdd     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-gnbnp     0/1     Evicted                  0             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-gsrs8     0/1     Evicted                  0             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-h69px     0/1     Evicted                  0             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-hcljj     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-hmxmk     0/1     Evicted                  0             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-hqngl     0/1     Evicted                  0             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-j2bx2     0/1     Evicted                  0             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-jjpkl     0/1     ContainerStatusUnknown   1             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-jqzlr     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-kbc25     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-khljn     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-kqht4     0/1     Error                    0             54m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-kqxf5     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-l52p9     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-l8x4p     0/1     Evicted                  0             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-ljhrm     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-m6l8c     0/1     Evicted                  0             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-n49br     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-q4z79     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-qgqch     0/1     ContainerStatusUnknown   1             15m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-qjrf8     0/1     Evicted                  0             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-qntzw     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-qv7s9     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-rkhq6     0/1     Evicted                  0             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-rl2g6     0/1     Evicted                  0             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-rl7dl     0/1     Evicted                  0             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-sbpw6     0/1     Evicted                  0             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-slww4     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-ssm24     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-txtjw     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-v9976     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-vl9gp     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-vns2z     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-vqcz9     0/1     Evicted                  0             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-vst56     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-w5hpg     1/1     Running                  0             8m53s
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-w8tbb     0/1     Evicted                  0             35m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-wpkwb     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-wvmtt     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-xp5t6     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-xtqwp     0/1     Evicted                  0             23m
category-product-kafka-67d4fdbf76-z56s4     0/1     Error                    0             23m
category-product-query-58897978b9-7csd7     1/1     Running                  0             54m
contact-adm-command-56bb8f75db-9pvvz        1/1     Running                  0             54m
contact-adm-kafka-858d968996-tgqkn          1/1     Running                  0             54m
contact-adm-query-6b6b7487bb-2mqp6          1/1     Running                  0             54m
gateway-7cbcb7bc4c-48b42                    0/1     Pending                  0             3m35s
gateway-7cbcb7bc4c-672mb                    0/1     Evicted                  0             42m
gateway-7cbcb7bc4c-d9hxn                    0/1     ContainerStatusUnknown   1             42m
gateway-7cbcb7bc4c-g97cs                    0/1     Error                    0             16m
gateway-7cbcb7bc4c-hpntm                    0/1     Evicted                  0             42m
gateway-7cbcb7bc4c-js7nc                    0/1     Evicted                  0             42m
gateway-7cbcb7bc4c-lctsk                    0/1     Error                    0             30m
gateway-7cbcb7bc4c-stwbk                    0/1     Evicted                  0             42m
gateway-7cbcb7bc4c-zl4rb                    0/1     Error                    0             54m
routes-cb9ffbb47-tmmw9                      1/1     Running                  0
```

an error in the container:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hc.core5.http.NoHttpResponseException: springboot:30002 failed to respond
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Classic HttpClient 5.0 support HTTP/1.1 version only. You need to
migrate to HttpAsyncClient 5.0 to be able to use HTTP/2. Check this [migration guide](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/migration-guide/index.html) for more info.which help to resolve your issue.

Comment: in my case I use tomcat that already comes with the spring compiler. In spring boot comes the parameter `server.http2.enabled=true`. but why do you think this is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED]

I made it work with StatefulSet see how my deployments look:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: gateway
spec:
  serviceName: "gateway"
  podManagementPolicy: "Parallel" 
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gateway
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gateway    
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: gateway
        #command: ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar","gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:gateway
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 30002
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred

---
 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: routes
spec:
  serviceName: "routes"
  podManagementPolicy: "Parallel" 
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: routes
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: routes    
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: routes
        #command: ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar","routes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:routes
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 30000
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred

---
 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: user
spec:
  serviceName: "user"
  podManagementPolicy: "Parallel" 
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: user
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: user    
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: user
        #command: ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar","user-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:user
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 30015
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred

---
 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: user-command
spec:
  serviceName: "user-command"
  podManagementPolicy: "Parallel" 
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: user-command
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: user-command    
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: user-command
        #command: ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar","user-command-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:user-command
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 30004
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred


---
 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: user-command-insert
spec:
  serviceName: "user-command-insert"
  podManagementPolicy: "Parallel" 
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: user-command-insert
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: user-command-insert   
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: user-command-insert
        #command: ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar","user-command-insert-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:user-command-insert
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 30003
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: category-product-kafka
spec:
  serviceName: "category-product-kafka"
  podManagementPolicy: "Parallel" 
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: category-product-kafka
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: category-product-kafka  
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: category-product-kafka
        #command: ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar","category-product-kafka-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:category-product-kafka
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 30008
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: category-product-command
spec:
  serviceName: "category-product-command"
  podManagementPolicy: "Parallel" 
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: category-product-command
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: category-product-command 
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: category-product-command
        #command: ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar","category-product-command-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:category-product-command
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 31533
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred

       
---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: category-product-query
spec:
  serviceName: "category-product-query"
  podManagementPolicy: "Parallel" 
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: category-product-query
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: category-product-query
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: category-product-query
        #command: ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar","category-product-query-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
        image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:category-product-query
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 30007
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

Services:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gateway-service
  namespace: default
spec:
#  clusterIP: 10.99.233.224
  ports:
  - port: 30002
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 30002
    nodePort: 30002
#  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: gateway
  
#  type: LoadBalancer
#status:
#  loadBalancer: {}

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name:  routes-service
  namespace: default
spec:
#  clusterIP: 10.99.233.224
#   protocol:  ##The default is TCP
#   port: ##Exposes the service within the cluster. Also, other Pods use this to access the Service
#   targetPort: ##The service sends request while containers accept traffic on this port.
  ports:
  - port: 30000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 30000
    nodePort: 30000
#  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: routes
#  type: LoadBalancer
#status:
#  loadBalancer: {}
#  type: ClusterIP
#  type: LoadBalancer 
#  type: NodePort

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name:  contact-adm-query-service
  namespace: default
spec:
#  clusterIP: 10.99.233.224
#   protocol:  ##The default is TCP
#   port: ##Exposes the service within the cluster. Also, other Pods use this to access the Service
#   targetPort: ##The service sends request while containers accept traffic on this port.
  ports:
  - port: 30001
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 30001
    nodePort: 30001
#  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: contact-adm-query
  
#  type: LoadBalancer
#status:
#  loadBalancer: {}    
#  type: ClusterIP
#  type: LoadBalancer 
#  type: NodePort
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: contact-adm-kafka-service
  namespace: default
spec:
#  clusterIP: 10.99.233.224
#   protocol:  ##The default is TCP
#   port: ##Exposes the service within the cluster. Also, other Pods use this to access the Service
#   targetPort: ##The service sends request while containers accept traffic on this port.
  ports:
  - port: 30005
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 30005
    nodePort: 30005
#  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: contact-adm-kafka

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: contact-adm-command-service
  namespace: default
spec:
#  clusterIP: 10.99.233.224
#   protocol:  ##The default is TCP
#   port: ##Exposes the service within the cluster. Also, other Pods use this to access the Service
#   targetPort: ##The service sends request while containers accept traffic on this port.
  ports:
  - port: 30006
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 30006
    nodePort: 30006
#  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: contact-adm-command


---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: category-product-kafka-service
  namespace: default
spec:
#  clusterIP: 10.99.233.224
#   protocol:  ##The default is TCP
#   port: ##Exposes the service within the cluster. Also, other Pods use this to access the Service
#   targetPort: ##The service sends request while containers accept traffic on this port.
  ports:
  - port: 30008
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 30008
    nodePort: 30008
#  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: category-product-kafka

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: category-product-command-service
  namespace: default
spec:
#  clusterIP: 10.99.233.224
#   protocol:  ##The default is TCP
#   port: ##Exposes the service within the cluster. Also, other Pods use this to access the Service
#   targetPort: ##The service sends request while containers accept traffic on this port.
  ports:
  - port: 31533
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 31533
    nodePort: 31533
#  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: category-product-command

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: category-product-query-service
  namespace: default
spec:
#  clusterIP: 10.99.233.224
#   protocol:  ##The default is TCP
#   port: ##Exposes the service within the cluster. Also, other Pods use this to access the Service
#   targetPort: ##The service sends request while containers accept traffic on this port.
  ports:
  - port: 30007
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 30007
    nodePort: 30007
#  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: category-product-query



---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cart-purchase-kafka-service
  namespace: default
spec:
#  clusterIP: 10.99.233.224
#   protocol:  ##The default is TCP
#   port: ##Exposes the service within the cluster. Also, other Pods use this to access the Service
#   targetPort: ##The service sends request while containers accept traffic on this port.
  ports:
  - port: 30011
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 30011
    nodePort: 30011
#  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: cart-purchase-kafka   

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cart-purchase-command-service
  namespace: default
spec:
#  clusterIP: 10.99.233.224
#   protocol:  ##The default is TCP
#   port: ##Exposes the service within the cluster. Also, other Pods use this to access the Service
#   targetPort: ##The service sends request while containers accept traffic on this port.
  ports:
  - port: 30012
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 30012
    nodePort: 30012
#  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: cart-purchase-command  

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cart-purchase-query-service
  namespace: default
spec:
#  clusterIP: 10.99.233.224
#   protocol:  ##The default is TCP
#   port: ##Exposes the service within the cluster. Also, other Pods use this to access the Service
#   targetPort: ##The service sends request while containers accept traffic on this port.
  ports:
  - port: 30010
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 30010
    nodePort: 30010
#  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: cart-purchase-query 

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: user-command-insert-service
  namespace: default
spec:
#  clusterIP: 10.99.233.224
#   protocol:  ##The default is TCP
#   port: ##Exposes the service within the cluster. Also, other Pods use this to access the Service
#   targetPort: ##The service sends request while containers accept traffic on this port.
  ports:
  - port: 30003
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 30003
    nodePort: 30003
#  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: user-command-insert

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: user-command-service
  namespace: default
spec:
#  clusterIP: 10.99.233.224
#   protocol:  ##The default is TCP
#   port: ##Exposes the service within the cluster. Also, other Pods use this to access the Service
#   targetPort: ##The service sends request while containers accept traffic on this port.
  ports:
  - port: 30004
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 30004
    nodePort: 30004
#  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: user-command

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: user-service
  namespace: default
spec:
#  clusterIP: 10.99.233.224
#   protocol:  ##The default is TCP
#   port: ##Exposes the service within the cluster. Also, other Pods use this to access the Service
#   targetPort: ##The service sends request while containers accept traffic on this port.
  ports:
  - port: 30015
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 30015
    nodePort: 30015
#  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: user
```