# Microservices in Kubernetes docker desktop and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, spring-cloud

In this question of [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75129358/spring-microservices-and-kubernetes-error?noredirect=1#comment132580261_75129358) Spring microservices and kubernetes error I asked why I was giving error in my rest api. After some research I have a doubt. Is it possible to use netflix-eureka-client and netflix-eureka-server with spring-cloud-starter-gateway in kubernetes from docker desktop?